# I need to take the lines from wc -l and put it into a variable

Tags: bash, scripting, wc

I need to take the number of lines and echo it in a statement like this:

```
echo "number of lines is: (lines go here)
```

I am using `cat names | wc -l` to get the number but I cannot seem to get it to a variable or even better to echo it.

Answer (score 3):

How about this:

```
 myLineCount=$( /bin/wc -l < $fileName)
 echo "number of lines is: $myLineCount"
```

Or you can skip the variable and embed the same directly into your echo statment like:

```
 echo "number of lines is: $( /bin/wc -l < $fileName)"
```

IHTH

Answer (score 2):

No need for cat:

```
echo "number of lines is: $(wc -l names | awk '{print $1}')"
```

Comment: Thankyou! I will mark this as right when time allows :)

Comment: This prints the word names.. how can I just print the number?

Comment: I've now edited it to omit the filename when printing.

Answer (score 1):

```
LNUM=`wc -l names | awk '{print $1}'`
echo "number of lines is: $LNUM"
```

Comment: I'd rather we teach newcomers to use `$()` instead of backticks.  Parens nest and are easier to read.